# Android ProgressBar getProgress?

Tags: android, progress-bar

Is there a slick way to display getProgress() in an Android ProgressBar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this example [android: how do i use the progress bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967337/android-how-do-i-use-the-progress-bar/2967466#2967466)