# Is there a way to make a custom VideoView progress bar without building a MediaPlayer from scratch?

Tags: android, custom-controls, progress-bar, media-player, android-videoview

I am currently making an Android app and I'm going to need to make a custom video player. I just need to change its ProgressBar color. Is there a simple way to do that?

I know I could do that using [Commonsguy example](https://github.com/commonsguy/vidtry). But it's not so good as the native video player and I think it would be making a lot for only a change of color.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: hope is useful for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967337/android-how-do-i-use-the-progress-bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up building a media player from scratch based on [Commonsguy example](https://github.com/commonsguy/vidtry). I've tried to use Android source code for a few classes. [MediaController](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html) looks exactly like what I needed to customize but it uses to many internal resources that we don't have access to.

Answer (score 1):

The native video player will be intrinxically linked to the system theme so changing the color is not possible.

You could try extendingthe native player and using it as a custom activity in your project, you might then be able to change the theme via your manifest.xml or in code.

Comment: I'm not sure to get what you're suggesting. Which class should I extend? MediaPlayer? VideoView? I don't see the point because there's no way to access the progress bar. Thanks for the comment though :)

Comment: the point point is that you can apply a style if the activity is in your manifest (assuming that the progress bar is a standard control)

Comment: Oh I thought of that solution but we can't access the progress bar. I'm trying to figure out how to find the progress bar, with no success for now.