# Pass seek bar progress from service to activity

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I'm creating a media player, in which the `MediaPlayer` is played in a `Service`.

Issue is I want to send the track duration progress to the `SeekBar` which is present in `Activity's` layout.

I stumbled upon several posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967337/android-how-do-i-use-the-progress-bar), but they all explain running the media inside the activity itself.

This is not a correct way, to continuously run a `Thread` within a **UI** thread.

I've not written the code yet, but I'm thinking to use [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html), to update SeekBar from within Service class.

But is there any better way. Will be great if an example can be provided.

*Thank You*

Answer (score 0):

Won't it be easier for you to sendBroadcast from Service containing the value for your seekbar and in the Activity in broadcast onReceive method update the seekbar?

Comment: Is sending broadcasts from Service to Activity every 1 sec, a good practice & efficient?