# How to have a ProgressBar circular and in determinate mode?

Tags: android, material-design, android-progressbar, progress-indicator

I have to download some images and videos on the device and I like to track the progress by having a circular ProgressBar in determinate mode in overlay to them.

The problem is that, no matter what, the ProgressBar is still indeterminate.

Is there a way to have it circular and in determinate mode?

*Layout*

```
<ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:progressTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:indeterminate="false"
                android:max="100"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/message_media_preview_progress"
                android:visibility="gone"
                />
```

*Code*

```
final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) mView.findViewById(R.id.message_media_preview_progress);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
progressBar.setProgress(0);
storageController.downloadMedia(context, message.getVideoFile(),
        new ProgressListener<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Integer result) {
                progressBar.setProgress(result);
            }
        },
        new ResultListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Boolean result) {
                if(result) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    setMediaClickListener(message);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Error downloading file",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not possible with stock Android ProgressBar. Look for external libraries: https://github.com/dinuscxj/CircleProgressBar

Comment: Ok, good, thank you. If you will put the comment in an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Wrote the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use Android ProgressBar in determinate mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967337/how-do-i-use-android-progressbar-in-determinate-mode)

Comment: Note that despite that duplicate question being about horizontal progress bars, it now has an answer explaining how to do so for circular progress bars as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with stock Android ProgressBar. Look for external libraries like:

http://github.com/dinuscxj/CircleProgressBar

Answer (score 1):

Now it is possible to have determinate circular progress bar in newer versions of [material design library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases):

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Refer [here](https://material.io/components/progress-indicators/android#using-progress-indicators) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Progress bar visibility.

1. Assign the id for the Progress bar.
2. Progress bar visible - Download button clicked.
3. Progress bar gone - onResult